# Sed Replace at a specific group of positions

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have a sample input file as below:

```
Apple   Orange      Gold    Silver Spoon Apple  Orange              Gold    
Apple          
Apple   Orange 
Apple   Orange      
Mango               Gold    Silver Spoon Apple  Orange
```

I need to check if the 15th to 20th position is Space and then replace it with a  string `Silver`. Also I need to completely replace the contents from 50th to 70th position with `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

Comment: How to handle lines that are of size less than 15/20 or resp. 50/70 ?

Comment: do nothing to those lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed 's/^\(.\{14\}\)      /\1Silver/
     s/^\(.\{49\}\).\{20\}/\1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/
'    <infile >outfile
```

Does it, I think.

Comment: Yes, however it should be 49 and 21 on the second line, since the `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` should start at the 50th position and since it looks like you want a number of characters equal to the lenght of the string to be present after in order to perform the replacement

Comment: When I try to do it for replacement above 255,  it is not working. Is there a work around to increase the sed maximum limit?

Comment: @Georgi  - I take you mean `s/.\{255\}...` is not working for some reason? What `getconf LINE_MAX` tell you? - it *should* be **>=512**.

Comment: $ getconf LINE_MAX
2048

Comment: @Georgi - but when you do: `printf %0256s | sed 's/.\{256\}//' | wc -c` the report is *256*? Because that doesn't make much sense. On the other hand, if you're going to be scaling it to that degree, it's probably worth considering a different tool - or at least some partnership of tools. Can I ask what system you're using? The above is POSIX - and any `sed` should handle up to *LINE_MAX* at least *(though the spec does indicate that it should handle more in pattern space)*, but some older `sed`s are not fully conformant. Also, what is the script you use exactly?

Comment: @Georgi - Why don't you try giving me a clearer idea of what you're about, as well? There's a lot which can be done w/ `P;D` commands which can make such things unnecessary.

Comment: I am little new to this all i want is i need to take a file and make some replacements the fields start above 2000, i am in a ksh GNU is not there i suppose. Sorry If i am not much help

Comment: @Georgi - it's ok. If you want to work on line-lengths above 2000, it might be worth breaking them out to sensible sizes first. Have you tried `cut -c[num]`? It will cut out chars by count like `cut -c-15,20-50,70-2000,2050- <input` would keep only the bytes 1-15, 20-50, 70-2000, and 2050-EOL. But it wont do regexp - so some kind of filter/pipeline might be called for. If you can work on answering my questions from before in more detail it maybe i can help further.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how smaller lines shall be handled (see my comment above) here is a `sed` solution:

```
sed -e '/^.\{14\} \{6\}/s/^\(.\{14\}\) \{6\}/\1Silver/' \
    -e '/^.\{49\}./s/^\(.\{49\}\)\(.\{1,21\}\)\?\(.*\)\?/\1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\3/'
```

and a much better legible (and less error-prone) GNU `awk` version:

```
awk '
  BEGIN { FIELDWIDTHS = "14 6 29 21 999" ; OFS = "" }
  $2 == "      " { $2 = "Silver" }
  $4 != ""       { $4 = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" }
  { print }
'
```

**Explanation:**

**1.) sed:** The `sed` command is built by two independent substitutions, the first handles the "Silver" case the second the "xxx..." one. The `sed` substitutions are of the form:

```
/pattern/s/pattern2/replacement/
```

The respective substitution is performed if the first pattern matches, and for those lines the second pattern is replaced by the replacement expression. The details are the `sed` typical cryptic expressions:

`.` - an arbitrary character

`\{14\}` - a repetition of the preceding subexpression (here 14 times)

`\(expr\)` - a subexpression that may be referenced in the replacement string by `\1`, `\2`, etc., where the actual number is defined by the n'th parenthesis expression

`\?` - specifies that the preceding subexpression is an optional part

**2.) awk:** The `awk` program runs the `BEGIN` section once, and the subsequent sections for each line of the data file, and the respective right hand action `{...}` only if the respective left hand condition is true.

`FIELDWIDTHS` - specifies the width of the data fields in the input lines, so that each field can be addressed by `$i` (for some field number i )

`OFS=""` - an empty string; the output fields shall not get any additional separation

`$2 == "      "` - if the second field (according to the `FIELDWIDTHS` specification) contains six blanks then replace it by the given string

`$4 != ""` - if the fourth field contains data replace it by the "xxx..." string

`{ print }` - an unconditional print of the current line, which was either modified by one or both of the preceding actions or shows the unmodified line otherwise

Comment: since I am new to this, can you explain what we are doing above? thanks for that

Comment: @Georgi; I added an explanation.

Comment: What errors do you propose can be had? And how is `.\{14\}` *illegible* exactly? And by the way `\?` does not specify *optional* in any but a few `sed`s. `\{0,1\}` would, though, POSIXly. In fact - the `awk` is far less legible - it doesn't even say what it does. I've downvoted this because it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @mikeserv; Are you serious? - `sed` is per se already extremely cryptic, and when you need to add specific meta-characters you need to **escape** all those characters; this is very unreadable by any sensible comparison. You just need to have an unbiased look at the `sed` code, it looks more like morse code than like a program. - And now compare that to the `awk` program. - And, WRT errors, you just need to observe in practice how folks write `sed` code, and correct it multiple times, rinse repeat, until it works. - `sed` is a low level language with all inherent drawbacks of such beasts.

Comment: @mikeserv; The downvote is of course your choice. All I can do is to shake my head, given your statement why you did. - Why wouldn't it "make sense" in your opinion? - Specifying the fieldwidths of the data for ease of processing in semantical units is extremely convenient in the given case.

Comment: I would happily remove the downvote, but your awk program is a lot less immediately sensible than the sed program you wrote here, which clearly indicates exactly how many characters per line it will affect and in what way, except your sed doesnt work in many cases. But your answer seems to state the opposite, which is weird and worth downvoting.

Comment: And by the way, at least I gave a good reason, which is more than can be said for some, I think,

Comment: Also, you did make your `sed` a *LOT* less legible than it needs to be: `sed '/.\{14\}/s/\{.14\}...` is completely redundant - `sed` doesn't perform a substitution if it cannot happen.  In fact, you do that in both cases. Why?

Comment: @mikeserv; All you said is that you find the `awk` version in my answer to not be "sensible". This is certainly not a "good reason". - Moreover, you seem not to have noticed that the "fieldwidths" is actually reflecting the requirements of the question and the thinking in character based columns. - So elegance of a solution is obviously in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: And no, I said that the *awk is less immediately sensible... except your `sed` doesn't work in many cases... your answer seems to indicate the opposite.* You talk about bias, but this answer is *all bias* - it's obviously written with some kind of agenda - which in itself is worth a downvote, because discouraging anyone from learning the efficient use of certain tools for no good reason is absurd and irresponsible. And, what's more, the answer contains technical errors - which is again worth downvoting. I also explained all of these things fairly openly - my conscience is clear here.

Comment: @mikeserv; The point is that (without making much noise or downvotes) I tested **your** code before and it seemed to not have worked correctly; in the "Mango" line the "Orange" will not be overwritten. My version, OTOH, does that. - Given that the OP's question was not very accurate it would not be an issue for me to criticize your code because of that. - This dispute is all too heated, not sure what drove you; it seems it was my legibility statement that offended you. - And now you're talking about "efficient use of tools" and "discouragement"; a neat `awk` code pattern is **encouraging**!

Comment: There's no indication that anything but spaces should be overwritten - I would consider overwriting something an error here - that behavior should be explicitly requested. And what drove me is exactly what I said - technical errors and obvious bias. The last thing though is why I bothered to comment at all - it is my hope that the other things will be corrected so that I might remove *(and - better)* reverse my vote.

Comment: @mikeserv; No, I was not talking about the spaces, I was talking about the final "Orange" that should be overwritten by "xxx....xx", where the OP asks for *"completely replace the contents from 50th [...]"*. - WRT the vote; unfortunately there was so much noise in your comments that I am reluctant to change the `sed` code - I would even remove it if your `sed` code did the same -, and since you have principle reservations against my `awk` code I accept your vote.

Comment: Well of course it won't be - that line doesn't meet the specifications requested - which is that the 50th *through* 70th position be overwritten. If there *isn't* a 70th position, it doesn't meet those specs. If the asker were to say *any position up to and including*...  could just use `\{1,20\}` and it would handle all cases automatically.I have no principle reservations against your code - code is code - I take issue with your *agenda* - which is just noise and irresponsible. Your `sed` code, though, is bad.

Comment: @janis I tried out the awk solution - it works, but only thing is it removes all the whitespaces between remaining fields, does this solution require me to define all the fields in the input file? or is there a way other than print so that the original input file format is preserved?

Comment: @Georgi; It works for me with your sample data. - You don't need "to define all the fields in the input file". - Are you sure you have used exactly my program? - You can check how the whitespace is handled if you change the `{ print }` action to this: `{ print $0 "|" }` (so that the lines will be terminated by a visible `|`) and you will see that all original whitespace is kept intact. - Or do you work with different data than posted so that we have to consider another data format?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that lines containing less than 21 characters (for the first replacement) and that lines containing less than 70 characters (for the second replacement) should be discarded, using Perl:

```
< inputfile perl -pe 's/^(.{14}) {6}/$1Silver/; s/^(.{49}).{21}/$1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/' > outputfile
```

Assuming that lines containing less than 21 characters (for the first replacement) and that lines containing less than 70 characters (for the second replacement) should be padded with spaces first, using `awk`+Perl:

```
< inputfile awk '{printf "%-70s\n", $0}' | perl -pe 's/^(.{14}) {6}/$1Silver/; s/^(.{49}).{21}/$1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/' > outputfile
```

**Command #1 breakdown**:

- `< inputfile`: redirects the content of `inputfile` to `perl`'s `stdin`
- `-p`: forces Perl to print the lines
- `-e`: forces Perl to read a line of program from the arguments
- `> outputfile`: redirects the content of `perl`'s `stdout` to `outputfile`

**Command #2 breakdown**:

- `< inputfile` in `awk`: redirects the content of `inputfile` to `awk`'s `stdin`
- `{printf "%-70s", $0}`: pads each line with spaces until the number of characters on the line is 70
- `|`: pipes `awk`'s `stdout` to `perl`'s `stdin`
- `-p`: forces Perl to print the lines
- `-e`: forces Perl to read a line of program from the arguments
- `> outputfile`: redirects the content of `perl`'s `stdout` to `outputfile`

**Substitution #1 breakdown**:

- `s`: asserts to perform a substitution
- `/`: starts the search pattern
- `^`: matches the start of the line
- `(`: starts the capturing group
- `.{14}`: matches 14 occurences of any character
- `)`: stops the capturing group
- `{6}`: matches 6 occurences of a  character
- `/`: stops the search pattern / starts the replace pattern
- `$1`: replaces with the captured group
- `Silver`: adds a `Silver` string
- `/`: stops the replace pattern

**Substitution #2 breakdown**:

- `s`: asserts to perform a substitution
- `/`: starts the search pattern
- `^`: matches the start of the line
- `(`: starts the capturing group
- `.{49}`: matches 49 occurences of any character
- `)`: stops the capturing group
- `.{21}`: matches 21 occurences of any character
- `/`: stops the search pattern / starts the replace pattern
- `$1`: replaces with the captured group
- `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`: adds a `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` string
- `/`: stops the replace pattern

Sample output:

```bsh
:~/tmp$ cat inputfile
Apple   Orange      Gold    Silver Spoon Apple  Orange              Gold    
Apple          
Apple   Orange 
Apple   Orange      
Mango               Gold    Silver Spoon Apple  Orange  
~/tmp$ < inputfile perl -pe 's/^(.{14}) {6}/$1Silver/; s/^(.{49}).{21}/$1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/'
Apple   OrangeSilverGold    Silver Spoon Apple  Oxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxld    
Apple          
Apple   Orange 
Apple   OrangeSilver
Mango         SilverGold    Silver Spoon Apple  Orange  
~/tmp$ < inputfile awk '{printf "%-70s\n", $0}' | perl -pe 's/^(.{14}) {6}/$1Silver/; s/^(.{49}).{21}/$1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/'
Apple   OrangeSilverGold    Silver Spoon Apple  Oxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxld    
Apple         Silver                             xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Apple   OrangeSilver                             xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Apple   OrangeSilver                             xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Mango         SilverGold    Silver Spoon Apple  Oxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
~/tmp$
```